# Event Registration Form - Page Automatically Refreshing

Tags: civievent

On our event registration form, where a user can register someone other than themselves.  When they select 'Yes' to register someone else, a field appears where they can search for the person they want to register.  However, once 'Yes; is selected, the page automatically refreshes in about 3 seconds.  After the page refreshes, the form goes back to the original view as if the user just opened the registration form.

This is the only field that is causing the page to refresh.

Any thoughts on why the page is automatically refreshing and how to correct it?

EDIT: We are using Civicrm 4.2.6 with Drupal 7.34

Answer (score 1):

@stechsla,

Mate, that‘s a *really* old version of CiviCRM. There are literally hundreds of bugs on that that were fixed years ago. Definitely time you upgraded to 4.4 (there‘s a case to be made to get you all the way to 4.6!) - in my view there‘s little point in attempting to address this issue as an upgrade would likely fix this, a raft of other problems, and give you vital security upgrades, not to mention cracking new features, a faster system, and a slicker interface.

If you‘re interested in having your system upgraded then your sysadmin should be able to help you. If you would rather someone else do it, please contact myself (john@civifirst.com - proud presenter of a presentation called "upgrading your upgrade") or a CiviCRM partner agency, details of which are available on civicrm.org.

Comment: I know!  We inherited this code from a previous developer and are advising our client on the best course of action to take.  I appreciate your assistance.  Your feedback will definitely help us when we make the case to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Seems for this you need to delve into the code.

My experience of the events registration page is that it has changed throughout the different versions - please can you tell us which version of Civi you're on? And which platform & version?

With that info, if someone here can't answer, it may be worth asking a freelancer  (including your friendly neighbourhood JohnFF!) or agency to help.